# Error: Could not find or load main class start.HelloWorldSwing.class

Tags: java

I want to run below code but when I want to run it the message `Error: Could not find or load main class start.HelloWorldSwing.class` apears in the command line. What's the proplem?

```
import javax.swing.*;        

public class HelloWorldSwing {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run command without appending .class at the end as:

```
java start.HelloWorldSwing
```

And not as

```
java start.HelloWorldSwing.class
                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: you should be one directory up from start when you run above command.